# How to get rotated output of lists?

Tags: python, list

Could you help with an advice or redirect me to related topic..
I am new to python and programming and kinda stack here. I have to get the following output:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

but instead I get:

```
......
.OO...
OOOO..
OOOOO.
.OOOOO
OOOOO.
OOOO..
.OO...
...... 

grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for i in range(0, len(grid)):
  output = ""
  for j in range(0,len(grid[i])):
    output += str(grid[i][j])
  print(output)
```

Comment: Just swap i and j: `output += str(grid[j][i])`

Comment: `print('\n'.join(''.join(i for i in x) for x in zip(*grid[::-1])))` :D

Comment: @chrisz `print('\n'.join(map(''.join, zip(*grid))))` - beat ya :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the indexing to `grid[j][i]`. This also requires you to change your ranges to have the axis of the list line up (because your rows are now columns):

```
for i in range(len(grid[0])):
    output = ""
    for j in range(len(grid)):
        output += str(grid[j][i])
    print(output)
```

outputs:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

*You also didn't need to `0` for the start of the range because `0` is the default, as well as the  indentation should be `4` spaces, so I corrected that too :)*

---

This could also be done in a one-liner:

Either:

```
print('\n'.join(''.join(grid[j][i] for j in range(len(grid))) for i in range(len(grid[0]))))
```

Or:

```
[print(''.join(grid[j][i] for j in range(len(grid)))) for i in range(len(grid[0]))]
```

Comment: one-liners look complicated ) thank you for your such a great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You could use zip to traverse your grid in column order for printing :

```
for row in zip(*grid) : print("".join(row))

..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

Note that this assumes that row 0 in your original grid represents column 0 in the transposed version.  If you want a 90 degree rotation, then you will need to reverse the order of the row elements by using row[::-1]

```
grid = [['*', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for row in zip(*grid) : print("".join(row[::-1]))

..OO.OO.*
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are permitted to use a 3rd party library, this can be done with `numpy.rotate` and setting `k=-1` [i.e. 90% clockwise]:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.array(grid))

[['.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.']
 ['.' 'O' 'O' '.' '.' '.']
 ['O' 'O' 'O' 'O' '.' '.']
 ['O' 'O' 'O' 'O' 'O' '.']
 ['.' 'O' 'O' 'O' 'O' 'O']
 ['O' 'O' 'O' 'O' 'O' '.']
 ['O' 'O' 'O' 'O' '.' '.']
 ['.' 'O' 'O' '.' '.' '.']
 ['.' '.' '.' '.' '.' '.']]

for x in np.rot90(np.array(grid), k=-1):
    print(''.join(x))

..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```